# Height of CardView with elevation

Tags: android, android-cardview

I need CardView with shadow and with height 56dp.
But when I set elevation, the height of my CardView is decreased.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">
```

How can I avoid decreasing?

Comment: try android:elevation="4dp" instead of card_view:cardElevation="4dp"

Comment: What Android version are you testing on?

Comment: try set height of inner view and cardView height set to wrap_content

Comment: I guess it happens on android below 21 api?